# How to rotate a local axis of an object to another object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Using the following code I can rotate the local Z axis to another GameObject.

```
/// <summary>
/// Faces local Z axis to another target object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="target">Target.</param>
private void FaceTo(GameObject target){
    float damping = 0.03f;
    var lookPos = target.transform.position - transform.position;

    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);

    transform.rotation = 
         Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping); 
}
```

the result during the Update method is the following:

[image: Result]

Now I need to face to the object using another axis, not the Z axis of my object; for example I would use the positive X axis for obtain this result:

[image]

How can I modify my script? 
Unfortunately I do not know the math of Quaternions and Vectors and I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just append another rotation:

```
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(-90, Vector3.up);
```

Comment: Ok, imagine that using this method whit some test can I also align on Y axis right? Can you suggest me some link where I can study this?
Tnx!

Comment: Sure, y-axis is rotation about the x-axis (+90°). It is really just another transform. You can check with your input image. There is no need to include fancy math. It's basically the rotation that rotates your reference direction to the z-axis. Then, the `LookRotation` adds another transform that rotates the z-axis to the target direction. Overall, the reference direction is rotated to the target direction.